# ActionBar up button transition effect

Tags: java, android, animation

I have already created a method for an animation when changing activities when the back button is pressed.
The problem is that the actionbar up button has the default transition effect to the previous activity and I can't find a way to override that animation and use a new one.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Preferably this would be hardcoded in java

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just get the event "home back"

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no R.animator present in my setup. Any idea why?

Comment: Srry R.animator is a folder i added and anim_left and right are animations i created, you can use the default android animations in android.R

Comment: Saved my life I was wasting for days to make transition working properly.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
}
```

fade_in.xml (**R.anim.fade_in**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

right_slide_out.xml (**R.anim.right_slide_out**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: This is what I do too, but I wish there was a more efficient way to handle both the back button and home up at the same time!